# O autocomplete do styled-components parou de funcionar no vscode

Tags: styled-components

O autocomplete do styled-components parou de funcionar no vscode, isso aconteceu com várias pessoas com as quais tenho contato. em comum, temos a extensão vscode-styled-components instalada.

O que já tentamos fazer: Desinstalar a extensão e colocar outra, reinstalar o sytyled components.

Comment: Conseguiu resolver? Esse mesmo problema começou do nada aqui. O vscode tem vida própria : /